# Is a bathroom required by code to have a window or exhaust fan?

Tags: bathroom, windows, air-conditioning, ducts, exhaust-fan

The Fort Lauderdale, Florida unit is on the top floor and there is a duct for the unit's central air in the bathroom, but it doesn't have a window or exhaust fan. Is this not to code? What are my options if an exhaust duct isn't available or the association doesn't allow installing one? The condo has been completely remodeled and I'm afraid the bathroom (or the rest of the unit if I have to leave the door open) will get ruined in no time without a proper exhaust for steam, since the weather here is already constantly humid.

Comment: So here's the situation. I assume you own the condo. Building code obviously didn't require one at the time of construction, and any tenant-related codes probably don't apply. You should start by looking into adding a fan. If that doesn't float, interior circulation might be your only option.

Comment: How good are ductless exhaust fans compared to a regular one? I own the condo but it is technically a co-op, so getting the association's approval for anything outside my unit may prove difficult.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. Feel free to post a new question. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance.

Comment: You might also revise to either ask about code requirements or a solution, but not both. It's difficult to provide a good Q&A answer with that ambiguity.

Comment: I believe your concerns are valid as excess humidity can indeed cause mold, mildew, and property damage over time.  Have you actually requested approval for adding an exhaust fan with your condo association?

Comment: My apologies. I have not requested approval yet. My intention about mentioning the code part was to see if I have any leverage in getting such an approval. I am unsure to check how this applies to my local community, let alone my building. I found this, not sure if it applies. On line f:
https://library.municode.com/fl/fort_lauderdale/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=COOR_CH9BUCO_ARTVIMIHOCO_DIV3STRE_S9-278LIVE

Comment: Adding a louvered grille to the door is better than nothing, and could be enough. You might also want to use a waterproof paint like epoxy to prevent really expensive damage. A fan that circulates in/out of the room will likely work much better than a dehumidifier, which are more for long-term humidity control, and aren't great at dealing with short term burst of moisture.

Comment: Also, get in the habit of momentarily running your shower fully cold after/as you get out. This chills the floor and walls of the shower, allowing them to act as a condensing and self-draining dehumidifier. It can make a huge diff if ventilation is poor. I used this method in an old tiny apt, mainly just to get the mirror un-fogged in a min or two instead of 5 or 10.

Comment: Wait, was this room built as a bathroom or are you converting it? I don't see how it would've been originally approved without an exhaust fan.  Unless it never had a shower... the humidity is serious business and you shouldn't shine that on.  Code does not recognize a dehumidifier as a substitute, and "ventless" exhaust fans are for kitchen smells.  Also if you have A/C you already have a dehumidifier since A/C and dehumidifiers work exactly the same way.

Comment: So by that you mean if I have the AC on during and after showering, that would be enough to minimize the moisture buildup so it doesn't damage anything? Would leaving the bathroom door open help that even more? And yes, the building was built in 1966 and the bathroom originally had a bathtub instead of a shower.

Comment: The AC may or may not provide enough circulation. It probably would, especially if it you run the fan 24/7. Leaving the door open or ajar would help a lot, as it allows convective forces (hot moist air rising) to help exchange the air, while minimizing back pressure on the AC vent.

Answer (score 3):

Codes differ between areas and across time. The International Residential Code requires SOME form of venting, either a fan exhausting to the outside with at least 50CFM or a window with at least 1-1/2 sq. ft. of opening area. Whether or not your locality adopted those standards at the time your condo was built is not something we can help with. But code or no code, an un-vented bathroom (with a bath or shower) is a bad idea and ESPECIALLY in a humid part of the world.

"Ventless" bathroom fans are only for fart control by blowing the air through a carbon filter, they have zero effect on humidity and the likelihood of mold and mildew formation.

Comment: Thanks. So if installing a fan and a duct is not possible, I hope a dehumidifier will be enough. The bathroom is small, albeit not tiny.

Comment: It can't hurt. If there is no way to vent, that would be your only option I think.

Answer (score 1):

This gets into an interesting discussion as to when something has to be "brought up to code".  This might be worth its own question/thread, but I'll put it out here anyway.

In many areas (your mileage may vary), your local jurisdiction/inspector may require that as part of a major remodel of a bathroom or kitchen for example,  that the bathroom/kitchen be brought into compliance with the current codes.  For a kitchen, this might mean having to provide 2 20-amp GFCI protected circuits for counter outlets, even if there was only a single 15-amp non-GFCI circuit there originally.  In a bathroom, it might entail providing the proper venting.

OP says his condo was completely remodeled.  To me that means it needed to be brought up to current code requirements, which means having the bathroom properly vented.  But being a condo unit, this may not have been practical.

The gray area is what differentiates a minor update from a major renovation.  Tearing a bathroom down to the studs is definitely a major reno.  Replacing a toilet - no.  Painting the room, NO.

Comment: The Building Code does not require a room be brought up to Code when you remodel a room. Where did you get that? (However, the Code does require what you do must be to Code.)

Comment: I didn't say the building code required that, but that the jurisdiction does (or may).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. They completely remodeled it in 2017 with permits, including the electric. The floors, molding, cabinetry, countertops, kitchen tile backsplash, and appliances are all new. I never managed to ask what was new with the electric specifically, but I know a few of the kitchen outlets are GFCI. As for the bathroom they replaced the bathtub with a shower, put in a new toilet, sink and tiling. Bathroom sink has a GFCI outlet as well. Here is a picture of it from the listing to give you an idea: https://i.imgur.com/8tei3a4.jpg

Comment: And a new lighting fixture in the bathroom.

Comment: @SteveSh Your first sentence in the second paragraph says “code compliant “.  That is not true. You should change that to “jurisdiction”.

Comment: @SteveSh I would upvote you if you changed it to “jurisdiction may require...” If not, I’ve got to downvote you. (Remember, this site is trying to get answers (info) correct.)

Comment: @Lee Sam - I agree about making sure the answers/info provided is correct.  I word-smithed my answer a bit.